# Remove string with spaces and quotes from xml file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, xml

I would like to remove the string
    `currencyId="GBP"`   from an xml file. Please note there is a single space before the first letter c. 
I am having trouble parsing the data and removing this string (including the initial space) would make it easier for me. I know I can use sed, but the space at the start of the string and double quotes seems to be tripping me up in my attempts so far.

To clarify here is an sample of the xml.

```
<location>Ethiopia</location><country>ET</country><shippingInfo>  
 <shippingServiceCost currencyId="GBP">2.83</shippingServiceCost>
<shippingType>Flat</shippingType>
<shipToLocations>Worldwide</shipToLocations></shippingInfo><sellingStatus>
<currentPrice currencyId="USD">157.5</currentPrice>
<convertedCurrentPrice currencyId="GBP">111.45</convertedCurrentPrice>
```

If I achieve my objective, the convertedCurrentPrice line would read:

```
<convertedCurrentPrice>111.45</convertedCurrentPrice>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed -i 's/ currencyId="GBP"//' file.xml` - This works for me. Add a `g` at the end of the sed command if you want to replace all instances.

Comment: Hi yes, I do want to replace all instances, I added the g as you suggested like so      sed -i 's/ currencyId="GBP"//g'        and it worked , thanks for that

Comment: hello again, I've tried to use your suggestion with a different string and this one is problematic   the string I now want to remove is        </sellingStatus>         (I want to remove every character including the slashes and <>) any ideas?

Comment: Hi @bms9nmh , please create a new question instead of asking questions in comments.

Comment: @bms9nmh : you can update your question too.

Comment: new question created here:   http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/275971/remove-string-with-and-backslash-from-xml-code

Answer (score 0):

As you have not specified whether you want to replace the string globally or not, I am assuming it to replace for specific line, so command would be,

```
sed -i '6s+ currencyId="GBP"++' filename.xml
```

It's better to backup the file before editing, so to be on safer side I would use,

```
sed -i.bak '6s+ currencyId="GBP"++' filename.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

The `xmlstarlet` command

```bsh
xmlstarlet ed -d '//convertedCurrentPrice/@currencyId[. = "GBP"]' file.xml
```

would delete all `currencyId` attributes from all `convertedCurrentPrice` nodes in the whole document, given that the attribute's value was `GBP`.