# Remove string with > and forward-slash from xml code

Tags: shell-script, xml

I want to remove two strings globally from some xml code. They are:

```
 </sellingStatus>
```

and

```
 <sellingStatus>
```

I have tried the following unsuccessfully:

```
sed -i 'sed -i 's/</sellingStatus>//g' file.xml
```

The slashes and greater than/lesser than symbols cause have caused issues with my attempts so far.
How can I remove these strings with the correct syntax?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not always a good idea to `sed` xml file, however

```
sed -i -e 's:</sellingStatus>::g' -e 's:<sellingStatus>::g' file.xml
```

substitute command in sed can be delimited by arbitrary char. (here `:`  )

Answer (score 1):

Use `s:::g` rather than `s///g` in your example not to escape '/' symbol:

```
sed -i 's:</\?sellingStatus>::g' file.xml
```